# Hiding DIV from left size while resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, layout

Is there any possibility to hide DIV from the left side when resizing a browser window?

I'm trying to do this because of correct displaying the ad, example is here [jsfiddle.net/h3b8g](http://jsfiddle.net/h3b8g/).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"><img src="http://s11.postimg.org/a1hfwxgs3/left_428x600.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="right"><img src="http://s1.postimg.org/tn5copctb/right_428x600.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="center">
    <div id="top"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1403808655.swf?clickthru=http://goo.gl/dKvOYd" width="1000px" height="100px"></object></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates consectetur veritatis fugit aspernatur quo repellendus corrupti perferendis inventore dignissimos sapiente ea ullam libero consequatur voluptatibus quam sint deleniti dolor illo molestias numquam ex iusto incidunt quidem.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 500px;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 500px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#center {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -8px auto 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: black;
    height: 2500px;
}

#top {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Or is there another layout solution to do this?

Comment: Which `div` are you trying to hide?

Comment: the #left - i need to have '02' mark on the image visible always (for higher resolutions, if the resolution is smaller, no div of #right and #left is visible) so i need to have always visible the right side of the image in the #left div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I have found two solutions. I think that solution 2 is better because of better browser compatibility.

### Solution 1: CSS 3

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 500px;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimg.org/a1hfwxgs3/left_428x600.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 500px top;
    height: 600px;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 500px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('http://s1.postimg.org/tn5copctb/right_428x600.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}

#center {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -8px auto 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: black;
    height: 2500px;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"><a href="http://goo.gl/dKvOYd"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/ukh7iv9e9/empty.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="right"><a href="http://goo.gl/dKvOYd"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/ukh7iv9e9/empty.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="top"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1403808655.swf?clickthru=http://goo.gl/dKvOYd" width="1000px" height="100px"></object></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Solution 2: empty images

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 500px;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    background-image: url('http://s28.postimg.org/mwcqxhk4t/left.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 600px;
}

#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 500px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('http://s13.postimg.org/rfq1vrwx3/right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 600px;
}

#center {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -8px auto 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: black;
    height: 2500px;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"><a href="http://goo.gl/dKvOYd"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/ukh7iv9e9/empty.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="right"><a href="http://goo.gl/dKvOYd"><img src="http://s14.postimg.org/ukh7iv9e9/empty.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="top"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1403808655.swf?clickthru=http://goo.gl/dKvOYd" width="1000px" height="100px"></object></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?  [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/h3b8g/5/)

Here is what did.  You need to embrace the float element but it is responsive. There are other ways but this give you some fluidity with much effort.

Here is the CSS:

```
#outterwrapper {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#wrapper {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
}
#right, #left {
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
}
#left {
    float:left;
}
#left img {
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    border-right:#000 5px solid;
}
#right img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border-left:#000 5px solid;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}
#center {
    width:80%;
    min-height:800px;
    float:right;
    background: black;
}
#center p {
    text-align : center;
    color:#fff;
}
#top {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#top object {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
div id="outterwrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/a1hfwxgs3/left_428x600.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <div id="top">
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1403808655.swf?clickthru=http://goo.gl/dKvOYd"></object>
            </div>
            <p>In this place you need to have enought content or set a min-height.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/tn5copctb/right_428x600.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but this solution is not ok for me, i need fixed width for the center div.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I can set fixed widths here I just did not at the time.  Sorry about the long delay I was traveling.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
display: none 
in the css of the div that you want to make invisible. you'll have to use display: none in every media query where you don't want this div to be visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, yes but I don't want to have div invisible always, sometimes i need to have visible only half of div for example so media queries to do this are unuseful.